# Mysql - Find items with coordinates inside viewport

Tags: php, mysql, coordinates, google-places-api

I have a mysql table (innoDB) that contain restaurants, each restaurants have Latitude and Longitude fields (separate columns in the table).

I am using google place API Autocomplete for customer to look for a location on globe, when this happens i get back from google "view port"

Example

```
["viewport"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["northeast"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["lat"]=>
      float(52.4309497)
      ["lng"]=>
      float(5.0683726)
    }
    ["southwest"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["lat"]=>
      float(52.3182742)
      ["lng"]=>
      float(4.7288559)
    }
```

My questions is how with the view port i get from google, i can search all restaurants inside ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do that:

- use [BETWEEN min AND max](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

**Example**:
`select * from TABLE where` latitude`BETWEEN [northeast lat] and [southwest lat] and`longitude `BETWEEN [southwest lng] and [northeast lng]`

- use the >= and <= operators

**Example**:
`select * from TABLE where` latitude`>= [northeast lat] and`latitude`<= [southwest lat] and`longitude`>= [southwest lng] and`longitude `<= [northeast lng]`

*Note1*: on my server the fastest query was using the BETWEEN

*Note2*: has you can see on MYSQL doc's BETWEEN is equivalent to (min <= expr AND expr <= max) in thereory they should be the same,but I decided to sudgest the >= and <= option to point out the fact that it was slower than the BETWEEN option :) I hope ti makes sense

Cheers